# Return cells that contain numbers with recurring digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a large dump of data containing in which column A has TOTAL AMOUNTS. In column B, I'd like Excel to simply say "yes" or "no" if the cell contains a number that has any digit recurring 4 times or more consecutively.
For example: if a cell contains the number 38,353.03 this would bring "no"
For example: if a cell contains the number 3,404,444 this would bring "yes"

I tried a formula using `LOOKUP(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(FREQUENCY(--MID(`
but that was a disaster

so I'm at a loss

Comment: Why doesn't `38,353.03` qualify? Are you excluding the decimals?

Comment: @VBasic2008 The repeated digits are not consecutive.

Comment: Now I'm curious, why would you want to check for consecutive same numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No add-ins are needed.

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*Some changes may be needed if the original data is TEXT, or if you are working internationally.

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TOTAL_AMOUNTS", type number}}),
    #"Add List of Digits" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "digits", each 
        Table.FromColumns(
            {List.Select(
                Text.ToList(Text.From([TOTAL_AMOUNTS])),(li)=>li<>".")},
            type table[Digits=text]), type table),

//Note the use of `GroupKind.Local` which matches on consecutive identical digits
    #"Consecutive Digit Count" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add List of Digits", "Consecutive Identical Digits", each 
        Table.Group([digits],{"Digits"}, {
            {"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}},GroupKind.Local), type table),

//Find the max count and return `TRUE` if gte 4
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Consecutive Digit Count", "Four or more", each 
        Table.Max([Consecutive Identical Digits],{"Count"})[Count]>=4, type logical),
    
//remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"digits", "Consecutive Identical Digits"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Or you can use VBA with a User Defined Function:
To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=FourPlus(cell_ref)` in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function FourPlus(n) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim sTest As String
    
sTest = Replace(Replace(n, ".", ""), ".", "")
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\d)\1{3,}"
    FourPlus = .Test(sTest)
End With

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This worked quite well, thanks a bunch! My fist time using this platform its amazing how great the community is

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then one could use the following to arrive at the desired result. The following formula uses a `LAMBDA()` helper function called `BYROW()`*

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(A1:A3,LAMBDA(α, 
  IF(OR(LEN(α)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(α,REPT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,4),))>=4),
  "Yes","No")))
```

---

- Using `BYROW()` which applies the `LAMBDA()` function to each row in the range and returns the output per row.
- `SEQUENCE(10)-1` function returns an array of numbers from `0` to `9`. The subtraction by `1` is intentionally done so as the array starts from `0` .
- `REPT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,4)` the function helps in repeating each number in the `SEQUENCE()` returned `4` times hence creating a string repeated numbers.
- Using `SUBSTITUTE()` function it removes the repeated numbers with an empty.
- `LEN(α)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(α,REPT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,4),))` gives the length of the cell, after removing it.
- `LEN(α)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(α,REPT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,4),))>=4` using it to verify whether the length is greater than `4` or `not`
- Using `OR()` to confirm at least one of returned output using the above is `TRUE`
- Lastly, using `IF()` to output as `Yes` if conditions are met and `No` when it doesn't

---

Alternatively, if one is not using `MS365`(assumed using `Excel 2021`) then can use the below one, which needs to be filled down for each cells:

```
=IF(OR((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,REPT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,4),))>=4)),"Yes","No")
```

---

For Older Versions -- From `Excel 2010+` onwards the following will work as well, however some of the versions may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode:

[image]

---

```
=IF(OR(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,REPT(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,10))-1,4),))>=4),"Yes","No")
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be:

`=SUM(1-ISERR(FIND(REPT(SEQUENCE(10)-1,4),A2*100)))`

or for older Excel:
`=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(FIND(REPT(ROW($1:$10)-1,4),A2*100)))`
or if it could happen that row 1 to 10 get deleted, you could use:
`=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(FIND(REPT({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},4),A2*100)))`

But I'm still curious for what purpose you're checking for these
(minimum 4) consecutive same numbers.

All these versions check for the number 0 to 9 being repeated 4 times as a string within the number value in the cell times 100 (to get rid of the decimal separator).

Comment: I am playing around with some numbers, and for auditing purposes mostly

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT(SEQUENCE(10,1,0,1111),"0000"),A1*100)))
```

it does work if the numbers are true numbers or valid numeric strings like "1,111" or "11.11" in my locale.

[image]

---

Have been thinking that there must be a lambda solution to this dealing with the string character by character but it's taken a while to work it out. The logic is:

Non-numeric: ignore

Same as previous character: append

Output has reached length 4 or more: preserve

Otherwise start again with current character.

```
=REDUCE("",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),
  LAMBDA(a,c,IFS(
    ISERROR(c+0),a,
    c=RIGHT(a,1),a&c,
    LEN(a)>=4,a,
    TRUE,c)))
```

The result will be either a string shorter than 4 characters or the first substring containing four or more repeated digits.

[image]

Comment: Yes that might be a good idea. Would it work for "0000" though?

Comment: If the number were an integer ending with 2 or 3 zeros, `A1*100` would make it a match.

Comment: @TomSharpe I forgot about the `0000` that requires TEXT. That way your sequence pattern suits alright. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Good point @VBasic2008. If the numbers are amounts in decimal currency though, I suppose it could be regarded as correct behaviour if it flagged up $100.00 as having four consecutive zeroes. I'll try and think of a way of avoiding it.

Comment: Thank you for this, and for the help you've all provided

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a problem for regular expressions

I use http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php add-in, you might be able to find others too.

With that you can simply write: `=IF(RegExpFind(A3,"(\d)\1{3}")="","no","yes")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out